# How to create to-dos based off existing cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a little problem that I'm sure can be solved in Excel, and I'd love to hear your ideas on how to solve it.

Here's the situation I have right now (or an equivalent): In Sheet 1, I have a list of the parties I'm planning. Each party has a date and a type (morning or evening). In sheet 2, I want to create a list of to-dos for each party. Here's an example: For a party on Friday, I need to send out RSVPs the Friday before and place a catering order on Monday. If it's a morning party, I don't need to buy any alcohol, but if it's an evening party, I need to place an order for alcohol by Tuesday. Etc Etc.

Here's what I currently have for Sheet 1:

```
+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
|   Date    |  Time   |        Description        |
+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
| 1/20/2018 | Morning | Smith Wedding             |
| 1/21/2018 | Evening | Jerome's Retirement Party |
| 1/26/2018 | Morning | Katie 7th Birthday Party  |
+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
```

Here's what I would like the corresponding Sheet 2 to look like:

```
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------------+
|   Date    |        To-Do         |    Party to do it for     |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------------+
| 1/13/2018 | Send RSVPs           | Smith Wedding             |
| 1/14/2018 | Send RSVPs           | Jerome's Retirement Party |
| 1/19/2018 | Send RSVPs           | Katie 7th Birthday Party  |
| 1/16/2018 | Place catering order | Smith Wedding             |
| 1/17/2018 | Place catering order | Jerome's Retirement Party |
| 1/22/2018 | Place catering order | Katie 7th Birthday Party  |
| 1/18/2018 | Place alcohol order  | Jerome's Retirement Party |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------------+
```

How can I make Excel create sheet 2 for me? Do I need macros or Visual Basic to solve it? I have many, many more than 3 parties, so it would take me forever to create each to-do myself.

Comment: Use a program like the (free) "[ToDoList](https://abstractspoon.weebly.com)" which you can create tasks in, create subtasks and then, using `ctrl` and left mouse clicking, easily select a group of subtasks which you can copy to another task. Don't try and bash excel into doing it, find the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion as starting point.

I think you can combine sheet 1 and 2. Add columns in sheet 1 with the type of to-do's, then use formulas to populate dates. Formulas would use if's for your morning/evening. Also, maybe have another column for type of engagement for special ordering. For example if type is birthday, have an additional column for cake order with a formula to give date.

I think you can pivot this sheet one to make it look like sheet two.